# Android Annotations not compiled with Ant

Tags: java, android, ant, android-annotations

After following all of the steps listed [here](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Ant), I found that my (Class)_ was still not being generated.

custom-rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="custom_rules">
<target name="-compile" depends="-build-setup, -pre-build, -code-gen, -pre-compile">
<do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
    <!-- merge the project's own classpath and the tested project's classpath -->
    <path id="project.javac.classpath">
        <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />
        <path refid="tested.project.classpath" />
    </path>
    <javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
           source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
           debug="true" extdirs="" includeantruntime="false"
           destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
           bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
           verbose="${verbose}"
           classpathref="project.javac.classpath"
           fork="${need.javac.fork}">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="compile-libs" includes="*.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
        <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
        <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}" />
    </javac>
<!-- bunch of if conditions here -->
</target>
</project>
```

Log:

> C:{path}{Class}.java (8:34) cannot find symbol class Activity_
>
> Note: Starting AndroidAnnotations annotation processing
>
> : Unclosed files for the types '[dummy1343240015623]'; these types will not undergo annotation processing

It appears that the processing begins *after* it cannot find Activity_. Error or as intended?

All of the files are in the correct location ( api.jar in \libs, .jar in \compile-libs ), and cannot for the life of me figure out anything.

**Edited:** Went poking around a little bit. Added in a new `property` for the AndroidAnnotations generated source folder, added that into the `javac` `src` pathing during `-compile` and still no luck. This first time I run the ant script, it tells me that it cannot find any of the generated classes, the second time, it tells me that I have duplicates of them all ( still gives me the `unclsed files for types...` error message ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, possible solution here. I needed to add a couple of edits to the javac compile itself, as well as have delete and mkdir above, so that it would constantly re-generate all of the files it needs and not barf on itself due to overwrite permissions.

```
<target name="-compile"
        depends="-build-setup, -pre-build, -code-gen, -pre-compile">
    <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
        <!-- merge the project's own classpath and the tested project's classpath -->
        <path id="project.javac.classpath">
            <path refid="project.all.jars.path"/>
            <path refid="tested.project.classpath"/>
        </path>

        <delete dir="${out.aagen}"/>

        <mkdir dir="${out.aagen}"/>
        <javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
               source="${java.source}"
               target="${java.target}"
               debug="true"
               extdirs=""
               includeantruntime="false"
               destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
               bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
               verbose="${verbose}"
               classpathref="project.javac.classpath"
               fork="${need.javac.fork}">
            <src path="${source.absolute.dir}"/>
            <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}"/>
            <src path="${out.aagen}"/>
            <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}"/>
            <compilerarg line="-processorpath ${processorpath}"/>
            <compilerarg line="-processor ${processor}"/>
            <compilerarg line="-s ${out.aagen}"/>
        </javac>
    <!-- a bunch of other crap that is unimportant -->
</target>
```